# Minus on Certain Condtiton

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any way to minus to data sets based on Condition?

Eg:

Table A:

```
id Count
1  2
2  1
3  4
```

Table B:

```
id Count
1  2
2  1
3  5
```

I want to get Table A `MINUS` Table B, Even if `B.Count >= A.Count` for the respective IDs as normally we have MINUS (Set Operation) operation based on equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
select A.*
from A
where not exists (
    select id 
    from B
    where A.id=B.id and A.count <= B.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.count - A.count as result
FROM TABLEB B
JOIN TABLEA A on A.id = B.id
WHERE B.count >= A.count
```